# How to Parse this JSON Response in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I want to parse these kind of Json responses :

```
{
"MyResponse": {
    "count": 3,
    "listTsm": [{
        "id": "b90c6218-73c8-30bd-b532-5ccf435da766",
        "simpleid": 1,
        "name": "vignesh1"
    },
    {
        "id": "b90c6218-73c8-30bd-b532-5ccf435da766",
        "simpleid": 2,
        "name": "vignesh2"
    },
    {
        "id": "b90c6218-73c8-30bd-b532-5ccf435da766",
        "simpleid": 3,
        "name": "vignesh3"
    }]
 }
}
```

I tried using SIMPLE JSON parser but this is not working for me:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(resp);
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONArray response = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("MyResponse");

//JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(yourJSONresponse);
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<response.size(); i++){
    list.add(response.get(i)("name"));
}
```

Comment: The JSON message isn't valid JSON so that may be your problem. I just checked your JSON string using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks @Sotirios Delimanolis i edited now

Comment: @nickebbitt Some parsers accept the `,`.

Comment: there is no `listTsmResponse` key in your json ...

Comment: @nickebbitt i edited and checked in http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String jsonString  = "{" + 
            "   \"MyResponse\": {" + 
            "       \"count\": 3," + 
            "       \"listTsm\": [{" + 
            "           \"id\": \"b90c6218-73c8-30bd-b532-5ccf435da766\"," + 
            "           \"simpleid\": 1," + 
            "           \"name\": \"vignesh1\"" + 
            "       }," + 
            "       {" + 
            "           \"id\": \"b90c6218-73c8-30bd-b532-5ccf435da766\"," + 
            "           \"simpleid\": 2," + 
            "           \"name\": \"vignesh2\"" + 
            "       }," + 
            "       {" + 
            "           \"id\": \"b90c6218-73c8-30bd-b532-5ccf435da766\"," + 
            "           \"simpleid\": 3," + 
            "           \"name\": \"vignesh3\"" + 
            "       }]" + 
            "   }" + 
            "}";


    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    JSONObject myResponse = jsonObject.getJSONObject("MyResponse");
    JSONArray tsmresponse = (JSONArray) myResponse.get("listTsm");

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i<tsmresponse.length(); i++){
        list.add(tsmresponse.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
    }

    System.out.println(list);
}   
}
```

Output:

```
[vignesh1, vignesh2, vignesh3]
```

*Comment:* I didn't add validation

**[EDIT]**

other way to load json String

```
    JSONObject obj= new JSONObject();
    JSONObject jsonObject = obj.fromObject(jsonString);
    ....
```

Comment: am getting error like "The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined"

Comment: ...
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject myResponse = 
 jsonObject.getJSONObject("MyResponse");
...

Comment: which version You are using

Comment: @MaximShoustin can you send a direct link? Couldn't find related results.

Answer (score -1):

You can do simply:

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject(resp);
```

Then you can use depending on the type of the variable something like:

```
int count = response.getint("count");
```

or

```
JSONArray tsm = response.getJSONArray(listTsm)
```

Then if you want to iterate through the objects inside you use just a for for it.