# get field list from json object list with Jackson

Tags: json, parsing, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

I have JSON data that is getting from api, I want to get list of a field inside of json data.

JSON data :

```
    [  
       {  
          "code":"en",
          "native":true,
          "plurals":{  
             "length":2,
             "forms":[  
                "one",
                "other"
             ]
          }
       }, {  
          "code":"de",
          "native":true,
          "plurals":{  
             "length":2,
             "forms":[  
                "one",
                "other"
             ]
          }
       }, {  
          "code":"le",
          "native":true,
          "plurals":{  
             "length":2,
             "forms":[  
                "one",
                "other"
             ]
          }
       }
]
```

I want to get code fields data as `list<String>` like below :

```
["en","de","le"]
```

what is the easiest way to do this?

Note :  I am using Spring's RestTemplate to get data.

Comment: do you have a dto class ?

Comment: @CodeIsLife No, Do I need ?

Comment: @CodeIsLife if I need I can create one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`findValues`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#findValues(java.lang.String)) method to extract the value of all properties named "code":

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = om.readTree(json);

List<JsonNode> code = tree.findValues("code");
```

Running it on your example data gives the result

```
["en", "de", "le"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        String jsonString  = jsonResponseFromApi;

        JSONObject obj= new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jsonObject = obj.fromObject(jsonString);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0; i<jsonObject.length(); i++){
            list.add(jsonObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("code"));
        }

        System.out.println(list);
    }   
    }
```

Refer below thread for more details [How to Parse this JSON Response in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899232/how-to-parse-this-json-response-in-java)